# Get latest exchange rate using command line?

Tags: command-line, wget

I search for a way to get the last exchange rate online using the command line. I want to use it with another program. Until now all I have is this:

```
wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=inr&hl=es" |  sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g';
```

Not my code, found on web.

It will output to console, but I need to save it in a file or to a variable in other program that will call that command. I don't have experience with wget and couldn't find any other way to do what I want. Is there any program (Windows is preferred, but *nix is acceptable) to do that or is there a way with wget?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the value of an environment variable to the output of a command in a Windows batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1446257/how-to-set-the-value-of-an-environment-variable-to-the-output-of-a-comm) If you’re asking what website to use to get exchange rates, that’s off-topic as a request for a product or service recommendation. If you’re asking how to extract one value from a website’s response, this is unclear, because you don’t show the raw input or the value you want to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a site that provides forex information in an automation-friendly way, then you can forgo the call to `sed` altogether and just use the `-O` switch for `wget`. Until then, the command you found works fine with Windows ports of [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm); you only have to make a couple of little tweaks. First, you have to replace the single-quotes in the call to `sed` with double-quotes and remove the trailing semi-colon. Second, you need to redirect the final output to a file or environment variable instead of the console.

- For console output:

  ```
  wget -qO- "google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=inr" | sed "/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g"
  ```
- For file output (adjust filename and path as necessary):

  ```
  wget -qO- "google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=inr" | sed "/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g" > forex_%date%.log
  ```
- For variable output (adjust variable name as necessary):

  ```
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('wget -qO- "google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=inr" ^| sed "/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g"') do @set forex=%%i
  ```

Comment: hi, when I try to use this command it returns ERROR 403 forbidden. does it is possible that now (2018) google is preventing calls from non-browser clients? is that service or other equivalent available?

Answer (score 1):

That command should work in (almost) any UNIX or in Git Bash in Windows. If you don't have `wget`, then you can use `curl` instead:

```
curl -L "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=inr&hl=es" | sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g'
```

You can save to a file with:

```
the_cmd > rate.txt
```

Or variable with:

```
rate=$(the_cmd)
```

You might want to suppress `stderr` of the commands to reduce the noise. You can do that by redirecting their `stderr` to `/dev/null`, like this:

```
curl -L "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=inr&hl=es" 2>/dev/null | sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g'
wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=inr&hl=es" 2>/dev/null | sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Not sure if you need anything else. I don't know of a better tool to do this, in neither Windows nor *nix.

Answer (score 1):

Since http://www.google.com/finance/converter  is not working now,
replace it with xe.com
The following command will print EUR/USD exchange rate.

```
curl -s "https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/\?Amount\=1\&From\=EUR\&To\=USD"|awk -F 'EUR / USD' '{printf substr($2,14,7);}'
```

Comment: Welcome on the SU! I suggest to give some explanation, this site tries to be more than a code snippet copy-paste forum.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.