# How to set the value of an environment variable to the output of a command in a WIndows batch file?

Tags: windows, script, batch-file

How can I set an environment variable to the output of a command in a Windows batch file? The command will return a single value of around 32 characters (e.g. type myfile.txt).

Answer (score 6):

Try running these commands:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('mybatchfile.bat') do @set myenvvar=%a
echo %myenvvar%
```

Comment: Source https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/windows-batch-file-set-output-of-program-to-a-variable.996281/

Answer (score 5):

Temporarily:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('command to run') do @set example_environment_variable=%a
```

Permanently:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('command to run') do @setx example_environment_variable=%a
```

---

Sidenote, `set` sets it just for this command process/window, but `setx` sets it for the whole user/system.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my command has parenthesis in it. I tried to escape them with backslashes, but no dice. Here's the command I'm trying to use:

powershell.exe -command (Get-SSMParameter -Region us-east-1 -Name "SumoI" -WithDecryption $true).Value'

... and here's the error: ".Value') was unexpected at this time."

Comment: If you have a powershell cmdlet don’t use batch file magic, do it all in powershell.

Comment: @eckes Agreed, that's probably better. How do I concatenate the variable with running a command from Powershell? $Output = C:\MyCommand -AccessKey$MYVAR | Out-String

Comment: Setx doesn't use the equals sign. Replacing it with a space is better. If there's a chance of %a having a space in it, add double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
for /f "usebackq delims==" %v in (`echo new_value`) do set new_var=%v
```

> Why would somebody want to use this version?

According to `for /?` help, one may want to use it when dealing with double quotes in the file names (as a matter of fact, that's how I ended up here):

```
usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
                  where a back quoted string is executed as a
                  command and a single quoted string is a
                  literal string command and allows the use of
                  double quotes to quote file names in
                  file-set.

[...]

Finally, you can use the FOR /F command to parse the output of a
command.  You do this by making the file-set between the
parenthesis a back quoted string.  It will be treated as a command
line, which is passed to a child CMD.EXE and the output is captured
into memory and parsed as if it was a file.  So the following
example:

  FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`set`) DO @echo %i

would enumerate the environment variable names in the current
environment.
```